# Tridion Profiling and Personalization error: The user cannot be null. please make sure the WAI is configured correctly

Tags: asp.net, tridion

I have a ASP.NET page (index.aspx)  using profiling and personalilzation published from Tridion 2011 SP1. It simply displays one dynamic component presentation and a second dynamic component presentation if the user has previously viewed 3 pages tagged (via cat+keywords) as 'golf'.

I initiated the profiling by adding the TBBs 'Target Group Personalization' and 'Activate Tracking' to my default finish actions. I republished the page and saw it create the dynamic cp's with the profiling code, all was going well:

```
<tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:8-667-64" ComponentURI="tcm:8-668" TemplateURI="tcm:8-666-32"/>
<tridion:TargetGroup runat="server" ItemURI="tcm:8-667-64">
    <tridion:Conditions runat="server" Negate="false" Operator="AND">
        <tridion:Conditions runat="server" Negate="false" Operator="OR">
            <tridion:Conditions runat="server" Negate="false" Operator="AND">
                <tridion:Condition runat="server" Type="TrackingKey" Operator="=" Negate="false" Name="Golf" Value="3"/>
                </tridion:Conditions>
            </tridion:Conditions>
    </tridion:Conditions>
    <tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:8-667-64" ComponentURI="tcm:8-663" TemplateURI="tcm:8-666-32"/>  
</tridion:TargetGroup>
<tridion:IncrementKey runat="server" ItemURI="tcm:8-667-64" Name="Golf" ComponentURI="tcm:8-663"/>
```

Problem: When I view index.aspx in my browser it gives me the error:

***The user cannot be null. please make sure the WAI is configured correctly***

I checked the broker DB and there was no data there. I believe my cm_wai_conf.xml file is configured correctly. I read this article that suggests the WAI uses the environment variable REMOTE_USER which I added to windows and still no luck.
http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/UsingPandPinDistributedEnvironments.aspx

Has anyone experienced this error before and can help? 
I can provide my cd_wai_conf.xml file if necessary

Thanks in advance, your help is greatly appreciated, it's been driving me crazy!

**EDIT: Added config file**
The XML would not render in StackOverflow so I've added it on PasteBin:
http://pastebin.com/tHwqhwtq

Comment: Perhaps you could add your cd_wai_conf.xml so we can review that

Answer (score 10):

Thanks guys. You're right. The WAIModule wasn't correctly configured in the web.config of my site. My site was running under IIS7 integrated mode so I configured this as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
<modules>
    <add name="TridionWAIHttpModule" type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.WAI.WAIModule, Tridion.ContentDelivery" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/></system.webServer>
```

This gave me a new error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I changed my AppPool to Classic mode and added the following lines:

```
<httpModules>
    <add type="Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.WAI.WAIModule, Tridion.ContentDelivery" name="TridionWAIHttpModule" /> 
</httpModules>
```

The page then loaded and Profiling and Personalization worked 100%

Thanks a lot for you time here guys. I hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Perhaps you could consider accepting and voting for the answers that helped you. Also, please consider committing to the Area 51 proposal at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2 in order for us to get a dedicated SDL Tridion Q&A site

Comment: Well, you did help me out a little bit, but I'm afraid changing the AppPool to Classic did nothing for me. Still stuck on 'Object  reference not set to an instance of an object", sadly.

Answer (score 7):

I have seen this when you don't have a Presentation ID confifgured for the URL you are using to access the site in the cd_wai_conf.xml. By default I believe this uses `localhost`. Make sure you have a host URL defined for whatever URL you are using to access the site.

Also double check that your WAI module is added correctly in the web.config of your webb app. In IIS make sure you have the module in the correct location, this can differ depending on whether you are in IIS6 or higher, and whether your App Pool is in Classic or Integrated mode.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Here is my cd_wai_conf.xml file. I tried deleting the entire contents to see if the error changed but it remained exactly the same. This suggests to me that my changes are not taking effect. See below that I've set my port to 8081, it was originally 80. I think this update hasn't registered. I've restarted all Tridion services and the content manager COM+. I even rebooted the entire server and still this error. Do you have any other suggestions on how I can register my changes?

Comment: What URL are you using to access your page? Is it http://localhost:8081/index.aspx

Where is your config file located? and are other CD functionalities such as linking working also? And finnaly have you added the WAI HttpModule to the web.config of you Web App in IIS?

Comment: Agreed with Chris. First check that your WAIModule is (properly) enabled and then check that your request has a corresponding configured presentation (in cd_wai_conf.xml). Note that when you do not have the WAIModule enabled you will get exactly the error you get. If all are well till here and you still have the error...enable DEBUG logging (using logback.xml from config folder of your website) and check what warnings/errors you get. Another small tip: to retest after a configuration change you only need to restart the AppPool of the Website you're changing.

Comment: Thanks so much guys. You we're right. It's now working. I've added an answer because I couldn't add the coding lines into this comment. Thanks again, you've helped me a lot